# For a given directory, how do I concatenate the tail end of recently modified files to a new file?

Tags: command-line, grep, logs, apache-httpd, tail

In case there's a better solution to the problem, my goal is to be able to quickly analyze ALL recent apache activity in /usr/local/apache/domlogs. The usefulness of this is when the server load is going through the roof I want to quickly see which website(s) are getting hammered (and what URLs) without having to individually grep/awk everything in domlogs.

For example, I know I can get a list of the very recently active apache access domlogs using this command within the domlogs directory:

```
find -regex '.*\.\(com\|org\|net\|biz\|info\)' -mmin -1
```

Now what I'd like to do is concatenate the tail 1000 lines of each of those files into a new file so I can quickly analyze it and see where all the traffic is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-exec` option:

```
find -regex '.*.(com\|org\|net\|biz\|info)' -mmin -1 \
    -exec tail -n 1000 "{}" >> logs.txt +
```

Now all last 1000 lines of each files in domlogs is written to file `logs.txt`, separated by filename.

`-exec command {} +` tells `find` to run command with files found, the command line is built by appending each filename at the end. This option works line combination of `find` pipe to `xargs`.

See more:

- [POSIX find documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)

Comment: Superb, works great. Is there any way to suppress the headers that are automatically inserted into logs.txt, e.g. ==> ./mydomainname.com <==

Comment: @CantonBecker: I think no way, maybe you have to do it yourself.